# Discord.py temporary ban

Tags: discord.py

I just wanted to create a command where if my bot restarts it will still unban members.
here is my code:

```py
@commands.command() # kihagyva
    async def tempban(self, ctx, member: discord.Member,seconds: int, d,*,reason=None):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="TempBanned",
                              description=f"{member.mention} has been tempbanned", 
                              colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.add_field(name="reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="time left for the ban:", value=f"{seconds}{d}", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


        if d == "s":
            await asyncio.sleep(seconds*1)

        if d == "m":
            await asyncio.sleep(seconds*60)

        if d == "h":
            await asyncio.sleep(seconds*60*60)

        if d == "d":
            await asyncio.sleep(seconds*60*60*24)

        await member.unban()
        embed = discord.Embed(title="unbanned (temp) ", description=f"unbanned {member.mention} ", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You will have to store the data in a JSON or databse.

Answer (score 1):

So you can store it in a database such as sqlite, mysql/mariadb or mongodb.

In MongoDB you would have a collection that is like a table filled with user and guild ids and when the ban expires.

You would use a [Task](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) to loop either every minute or 30 seconds or can be longer. Iterate through a database and check if the `time now` and the `time stored` is less than the `time now`. Then unban them.